# How to put background gif in an <a> link when hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> How can I put background image when I hover a link

```
<html>
    <head> </head>
    <body>
         <a href="#">Insert Bg in this a when hover</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please show us the code that you tried?

Comment: `:hover` and `background-image` will help

Answer (score 1):

You need set the display property of the anchor tag to block and give it a height for the background to fill in.

HTML:

```
<html>
 <head> </head>
 <body>
     <a href="#">Insert Bg in this a when hover</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
a{
 display : block;
 height : 100px;
}

a:hover{
 background : url('http://i.giphy.com/xUySTCEXzJdGCeIj3W.gif');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) psudo-class selector and set [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) property.

```
a:hover {
  background-image : url(img.png);
}
```

```css
a:hover {
  background-image : url(https://placehold.it/100x15);
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head> </head>
    <body>
         <a href="#">Insert Bg in this a when hover</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `CSS`

```css
a:hover {
        background: url("http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/grey-wallpaper-hd/grey-wallpaper-hd-23.jpg");  
       //Replace the URL with the desired image you want as a Bg
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head> </head>
    <body>
         <a href="#">Insert Bg in this a when hover</a>
    </body>
</html>
```